# Pandas Dataframe - CNN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conv-neural-network, data-preprocessing

I have a pandas dataframe which has 8528 rows × 18287 columns. each row represents a bio-signal sample and has a label. I want to convert each row's data into an image(matrix) in order to feed this dataset to CNN to detect a kind of disease. As I mentioned, each row has a label of that disease. How can I do this? Here is the shape of the head of my dataframe:
[image: my dataframe]

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can. Let's say you want to convert this into a `(1, 18286)`-shaped array (then you can use kernel of `1 x N`.

```py
# Convert specific columns
matrix = df[list(range(18286))].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1, 18286)
```

matrix now has the shape of (N, 1, 18286), where N is the number of rows.
If you know which exact column the matrix data range is, you can alter the shape accordingly.

Note: If you want to have matrices of a different shape than `(1, 18286)`, then I have concerns regarding whether each row data has relations. CNN works best when there exists useful features that can be extracted from the kernel window.

Comment: thanks for your respond . I ran your suggested code and got this memmory error : "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1013. MiB for an array with shape (15572, 8528) and data type float64 "                                                                                                                                      have you got any idea dealing with this?

Comment: @jasmine Then I think it will be better if you loop by each row of the dataframe with `iterrows` and convert each line to a matrix individually, that would allows you limit the memory usage.